# What does the number after '@' symbol mean in IDA disassembly?

Tags: ida, disassembly, disassemblers

[image]

As you can see, IDA disassembly shows `r0@1`, `r5@5`, `[sp+0h] [bp-18h]@7` etc. Presuming `r0`, `r5` to be registers and `[sp+0h] [bp-18h]` to be a memory location, what does the number at the end signify?

Comment: Count the number of occurrences of `r0` in the disassembled code. Could this be *variable propagation*? (And then it'd the the *n*th occurrence of that register.)

Comment: JFYI, this is decompilation pseudocode, not "disassembly".